# Lynx browser access and braille

Tags: lynx, accessibility

[image: text based web browser]

Hello fellow Stack Exchange users can you please help? Does anyone know if there is an ability to adapt webpages for the braille alphabet within the Lynx browser?

This seems like the perfect web browser to have such a tool because it is already text based to start with.

Any ideas for web use with people that have visual disabilities to plug in a braille pad and have this work?

Comment: Does this fit your needs? https://brltty.app/

Comment: I am not blind, I am taking a class called "intro to disabilities" and I wanted learn more about information on this type of software. Thank you for your reply. This fits well as I am searching for and sharing this information with fellow students. I feel CSCI should at least touch on some of this software.